# file_field upload button appearing multiple times on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I have this code in my `_form.html.erb` file:

```
<%= f.fields_for :request_attachments do |ra| %>
    <div class="row westmontTextMuseo3" id="uploader">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <label class="btn btn-info"> Upload Files
                <%= ra.file_field :request_attachment_file, :multiple => true, name: "request_attachments[file][]", :style => "display: none", type: "file" %>
                <%= ra.hidden_field :file_cache %> 
          </label>
        <%= link_to(ra.object.file.url.to_s.split('/')[-1], ra.object.file.url) %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I can see why the `Upload Files` button appears. It seems like I want it outside the scope of the nested form, but I don't know how to do that.

My goal is to place the button once after it has provided links to each of the already attached files.

Any help would be great, thanks.

**Edit:** Other code to see if we can get it to work.

```
<%= f.fields_for :request_attachments do |ra| %>
  <%= link_to(ra.object.file.url.to_s.split('/')[-1], ra.object.file.url) %>
<% end %>

<div class="row westmontTextMuseo3" id="uploader">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label class="btn btn-info"> Upload Files
      <%= @request.request_attachments.file_field :request_attachment_file, :multiple => true, name: "request_attachments[file][]", :style => "display: none", type: "file" %>
      <%= @request.request_attachments.hidden_field :file_cache %> 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this fails with an `undefined method file_field' for #<RequestAttachment...`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. So - what have you tried to make this work? Have you tried just moving the field to where you expect it to be? what happened then?

Comment: I have tried an `if` statement to see if `ra.object.file` exists, but that will show the links, and not the button. I have tried moving the link_to object outside, using a `@requests.request_attachments.all.each do |x| ... ` but then the button still appears multiple times for each file.

and ... thanks for the welcome.... been here for over 2 years now, but a welcome is always nice

Comment: :D I base my "welcome" off how many points a person has - usually I guess right, but sometimes I guess wrong ;) Still - I'm glad it made you happy!

Comment: Yeah, you'll continue to get a field for every attachment if you put it inside a loop of any kind (whether that's `each` or `fields_for`) - if you want literally just one... then it needs to be outside of a loop. Can you show us an example of the other code you tried that only showed the links? maybe we can find a way to make that work.

Comment: ooh yeah this part probably won't work right. :( `<%= @request.request_attachments.file_field` - you have a form that's surrounding these fields right? something that will be submitted somewhere? usually it's called `f` and that's what you need to put the field on - something like: `<%= f.file_field  :request_attachment_file` ...

Comment: I think I just figured it out. By replacing the `@request.....` with `file_field_tag` and `hidden_field_tag`... I assumed that wouldn't work because it was a nested attribute, but since it only relies on parameters, it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to have worked

```
<%= f.fields_for :request_attachments do |ra| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= link_to(ra.object.file.url.to_s.split('/')[-1], ra.object.file.url) %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="row westmontTextMuseo3" id="uploader">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label class="btn btn-info"> Upload Files
      <%= file_field_tag :request_attachment_file, :multiple => true, name: "request_attachments[file][]", :style => "display: none", type: "file" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :file_cache %> 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assumed since the attributes were nested it wouldn't work, but it did work.